# Не отображается иконка в меню экрана после сборки

Tags: android, android-manifest

Как решит эту проблему помогите пожалуйста. При изменение в файле манифест значок пропал.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: прямо говоря, после правки ничего особо понятнее не стало. и то, что автор сам ничего не правит в вопросе вызывает сомнения, что ему этот вопрос вообще нужен -  уже два дня никакой активности в вопросе. проголосовал за "оставить закрытым".